# Undefined method in Ruby on Rails in .erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I have a problem with my project. It raises an exception that I have undefined method.

I have two entities Book and Subject. Here you have codes of Book_controller and the erb file where exception appears.

```
    class BookController < ApplicationController

def list
    @books = Book.all
end

def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id]) 
end

def new
    @book = Book.new
    @subjects = Subject.all
end

def book_params
    params.require(:books).permit(:title, :price, :subject_id, :description)
end

def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if @book.save
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
        @subjects = Subject.all
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @subjects = Subject.all
end

def book_param
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :price, :subject_id, :description)
end

def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])

    if @book.update_attributes(book_param)
        redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
    else
        @subjects = Subject.all
        render :action => 'edit'
    end

end

def delete
    Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'list'
end

def show_subjects
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

and the show_subjects.html.erb file:

```
<h1><%= @subject.name -%></h1>

<ul>
   <% @subject.books.each do |c| %>
   <li><%= link_to c.title, :action => "show", :id => c.id -%></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

There is a message:

```
Showing E:/Ruby/library/app/views/book/show_subjects.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `books' for #<Subject id: 1, name: "Physics">
```

I am a beginner in Ruby, it's my first project and I have no idea what's wrong. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Just for people who search for similar problem, I have not defined 'has_many :books' in my Subject class, so it has not had the relation between Book and Subject.